# Why won't this GP lineart modifier show up?

Tags: modifiers, camera, grease-pencil, lineart

[File I'm working with here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/uz9k5a9xrwqewhqewu04r/power-portrait-debug.blend?rlkey=2jbg3lyldfhkwjau3c87art1o&dl=0).

I'm trying to use a Grease Pencil lineart modifier on an object in a scene. This should be pretty straightforward, and indeed if I append the object (Mug) into another file and apply the modifier there, it works fine, but for some reason it abjectly refuses to appear in this file.

What I'm getting:
[image: What I'm getting]

What I'm trying to get:
[image: What I'm trying to get]

I've tried reviewing every step of process to get to this step, checked for hidden obstructions keeping the lineart from showing up, checked to make sure the keyframes were properly added, and for the life of me I can't figure out what is different in the file to keep this from working.